# ellipse comes after last button in datatable jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, datatables

[image]

The ellipse comes after last in page i have used sPaginationtype as well but still it gives me no change.

Below in my code

```
 table = $("#gridTable").DataTable({
            "pageLength": tableInfo.length,
            "displayStart": tableInfo.start,
            "processing": true,
            "searching": false,
            "serverSide": true,
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            "order": tableInfo.order,
            "dom": '<"top">rt<"grid-bottom clearfix"lip>',
            "language": {
                "lengthMenu": "Page Size &nbsp; _MENU_ ",
                "info": "Records _START_ to _END_ of (_TOTAL_)",
                "emptyTable": "No Record(s) Found"
            },
            "ajax": {
                url: '@Url.Action("SearchCountry")',
                type: "post",
                data: BuildSearchCriteria()
            },
            "columns": columns,
            "drawCallback": function (settings) {
                var api = this.api();
                if (api.rows({ page: 'current' }).data().length <= 0) {
                    $('#dataTables_info').hide();
                    $('#dataTables_paginate').hide();
                    $('#dataTables_length').hide();
                }
                else {
                    $('#dataTables_info').show();
                    $('#dataTables_paginate').show();
                    $('#dataTables_length').show();
                }
                InitDeleteConfirmation();
            },
            "rowCallback": function (row, data, index) {
                row.className = "ubs-row";
                return row;
            }
        });
```

.cshtml page

```
<div class="clearfix">
<div class="table-title">
    <div>
        <a class="btn sm-btn btn-icon btn-primary" href="@Url.Action(Actions.ManageCountry)"><img class="icon" src="@Url.Content("~/images/add-icon.png")" alt=""><sapn>Add Country</sapn></a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="table-responsive grid-table">
    <table class="table table-hover" id="gridTable"></table>
</div>
```

css related to this classes

```css
.table-title {display:table; width:100%; padding-top:15px; padding-bottom:15px;   }
.table-title h5 {padding-bottom:0px; font-weight:700; color:#565656;  }
.table-title> div {display:table-cell;vertical-align:middle; }
.table-title> div .btn {float:right; margin-left:10px;  }

    .clearfix:before, .clearfix:after { content: " "; display: table; }
.clearfix:after { clear: both; }
.clearfix { *zoom: 1; }

.grid-table.table-responsive {border:0px; margin-bottom:0px;}
.grid-table .table {margin-bottom:0px; border:1px solid #e1e1e1; }
.grid-table .table>thead>tr>th,  
.grid-table .table>tbody>tr>th, 
.grid-table .table>tfoot>tr>th,
.grid-table .table>thead>tr>td, 
.grid-table .table>tbody>tr>td, 
.grid-table .table>tfoot>tr>td {color:#535353; font-size:14px; font-weight:normal; vertical-align: middle; padding:16px 15px; border-bottom:1px solid #e1e1e1; }
.grid-table .table>thead>tr>th {color:#535353; font-size:16px; font-weight:700; background-color:#f6f6f6; white-space: nowrap;}
.grid-table .table .actions {width:110px;}
.grid-table .table .actions a {padding:0px 5px; vertical-align:middle; float:left; }
.grid-table .table .actions a:hover {opacity:0.5;}

.table-hover>tbody>tr:hover {background-color: #f9f9f9;}
.grid-table .table .icheckbox_square {position: relative !important; margin:auto; float:left;}
.grid-table .table .stop {width:100px; text-align:center;}


.grid-bottom{background:#fff;padding:15px;border:1px solid #e1e1e1; border-top:0px; margin-bottom:30px;   }
.paginetion{float:right; margin-top:5px; }
.paginetion ul{margin:0px;padding:0px;list-style-type:none;}
.paginetion ul li{padding:0;margin:0px;display:inline;}
.paginetion ul li a{font-size:14px; color:#565656;text-decoration:none;background:#fff;border:1px solid #d7d7d7; margin:0px 0px  0px -1px;padding:0px;height:38px;width:38px; line-height:37px;text-align:center;display:block;float:left;}
.paginetion ul li a.active,.paginetion ul li a.active:hover{color:#FFF;text-decoration:none;border:none;background:#1f79cd;}
.paginetion ul li a.prevar{background:url('../images/left-arrow.png') no-repeat center #fff;}
.paginetion ul li a.nxtar{background:url('../images/right-arrow.png') no-repeat center #fff;}
.paginetion ul li a:hover{text-decoration:none;background-color:#f0f0f0; color:#000;}

.show-record{float:left;font-size:16px;color:#616161;padding-left:0px; margin-top:2px;  }
.show-record .form-label{display:inline-block; margin-left:10px;}
.show-record .bootstrap-select:not([class*=col-]):not([class*=form-control]):not(.input-group-btn), .show-record .bootstrap-select {min-width:80px; width:auto; display:inline-block;}
.show-record .btn {min-width:80px; }
```

As per the suggestion i have added the code of css file as well.so please do consider this for giving reply of this problem

> Please Kindly help to solve this issue

Comment: may be there is problem in your html. any uncompleted html comment.

Comment: this type of thing occurs in all the files @Suresh Maurya

Comment: Maybe do you have a `text-overflow` property on the CSS?

Comment: yes but not applying in this datatable @Veehmot

Comment: The class is "ellipsis", are you doing anything special in the CSS for that? It would be worth posting the CSS here too.

Comment: no i haven't used  ellipsis class

Comment: I have append css as well @colin0117

Comment: I've no idea, sorry, I've been trying to reproduce here without any success. Would you be able to provide a link to a live page that shows this problem - it would help to diagnose?

Comment: At least post a screenshot of what `Inspect Element` tells you

Comment: Thank you for commenting on this post. I have got idea from here and i'll tried css for fixing it and it's done